# Left outer join involving 3 tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have 3 DB2 tables all having same key value columns. Now I want the data from table A with a condition along with the matching records from tables B and C.  Suppose table A has 100 records for the condition (say, COLX = 'Y') then all the 100 records from table A along with the matching key records from B & C should be extracted (A.COL1, B.COL1 & C.COL1 are the key columns) Can someone please tell me how this can be done using left outer join ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select * 
from A 
left outer join B on A.COL1=B.COL1
left outer join C on A.COL1=C.COL1
where A.COLX='Y'
```